# SQL SUM from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to build a SQL Sum statement to sum data from different tables.  Each table has a SalesRep field in common.  I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to to construct the SQL correctly.

I know the below syntax is wrong and won't work but I'm just not a SQL expert.  I'm sure it's something simple.  Can someone help me please?

```
SELECT SalesRepID, SUM(SELECT SalesRepID, Sum(tblClientAdditions.Amount) AS Subtotal
FROM tblClientAdditions GROUP BY SalesRepID + SELECT SalesRepID, 
Sum(tblAccounts.ReceivedAmount) AS Subtotal1
FROM tblAccounts GROUP BY SalesRepID) FROM tblSalesReps;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between the tables, right?

Than maybe something like this?

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table1) + (SELECT SUM(value) FROM table2) as result
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesRepID, 

(SELECT Sum(tblClientAdditions.Amount) FROM tblClientAdditions 
where tblClientAdditions.SalesRepID =tblSalesReps.SalesRepID)
+
(SELECT Sum(tblAccounts.ReceivedAmount) FROM tblAccounts
where tblAccounts.SalesRepID =tblSalesReps.SalesRepID)

FROM tblSalesReps;
```

Answer (score 0):

I added IsNull because if one of the columns are null you will get null in the answer and you don't want that.

```
SELECT ISNull(SUM(Table1.column1),0)+ (SELECT ISNull(SUM(Table2.column1),0) FROM Table2) FROM Table1
```

This works for me.